# Getting JOIN and WHERE to work together

Tags: mysql

Ok, I have an example table with the following information and query.
First up is the data, with the question following at the end.

Here's the SQL Dump:
http://pastie.org/private/o7zzajdpm6lzcbqrjolgg

Or you can use the included a visual below:

#### Purchases Table

```
|  id   |   brand   |    date     |

    1        b1       2000-01-01 
    2        b1       2000-01-03 
    3        b2       2000-01-04
    4        b3       2000-01-08
    5        b4       2000-01-14
```

#### Owners Table

```
id | firstname | lastname | purchaseid | itemCoupon | itemReturned | Accessories
 1     Jane        Doe          1           yes           no               4
 2     Jane        Doe          2           yes           no               2 
 3     Jane        Doe          3           no            no               1
 4     Jane        Doe          4           no            no               3
 5     Jane        Doe          5           no            yes              6
```

#### The Query

```
SELECT brand, COALESCE( SUM( inTime.Accessories ) , 0 ) AS acessory_sum
FROM purchases
INNER JOIN owners AS person ON person.purchaseid = purchases.id
AND person.firstname =  'Jane'
AND person.lastname =  'Doe'
LEFT JOIN owners AS inTime ON person.id = inTime.id
AND purchases.date
BETWEEN DATE(  '2000-01-01' ) 
AND DATE(  '2000-01-05' ) 
GROUP BY purchases.brand
```

This gives the following expected result:

```
| brand | accessory_sum
   b1          6
   b2          1
   b3          0
   b4          0
```

#### The question

Now, I would like to add to the query:

```
WHERE itemCoupon = 'yes' OR itemReturned = 'yes'
```

But this overrides the last join and when I do the same search above I get:

```
| brand | accessory_sum
   b1          6
   b2          1
```

Similarly I still want it to return `No results found` for `2000-01-04`, `2000-01-08` using     `WHERE itemCoupon = 'yes' OR itemReturned = 'yes'`. Removing the `WHERE` gives me zeros for all brands if I try to do it another way.

Basically I want to keep the way the `WHERE` behaves but also keep the format that I described in the first example of the expected output.

As it is now, using `WHERE` destroys the way the last `LEFT JOIN` works with `COALESCE` which fills the remaining `brand` rows with zeros.

Comment: but it _is_ returning the correct data. You changed the script and so the result is different as expected. The `b3` and `b4` items from the first result were omitted precisely because you added `WHERE itemCoupon = 'yes' OR itemReturned = 'yes'` Am I missing something here?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I made myself clear. I know I changed the script, I just don't know how to get `No results found` between `2000-01-04`-`2000-01-08` without using `WHERE itemCoupon = 'yes' OR itemReturned = 'yes'`.

Comment: Another problem is, for matching queries using `WHERE itemCoupon = 'yes' OR itemReturned = 'yes'` this breaks my 'expected output' that I showed in the first example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your WHERE turns the outer join into an inner join.

You need to move your additionally condition into the LEFT JOIN condition:

```
LEFT JOIN owners as inTime 
       ON person.id = inTime.id 
      AND purchases.date between purchases.date DATE ('2000-01-01') and DATE ('2000-01-05')
      AND (inTime.itemCoupon = 'yes' or inTime.itemReturned = 'yes')
```

Comment: Not sure why it didn't work the first time but when I tried it again it worked nicely. This only answers one of my questions though. I'll accept it and ask my other question separately...

Answer (score 0):

the ON clause when doing a JOIN is similar to the WHERE clause. So instead of trying to use WHERE, just add another AND to your query (and don't forget to use the parenthesis in the OR clause):

```
SELECT brand, 
COALESCE(SUM(Time.purchasedAccessories),0) as acessory_sum
FROM purchases 
INNER JOIN owners AS person 
ON person.purchaseid = purchases.id 
AND person.firstname = 'Jane' 
AND person.lastname = 'Doe'

AND (person.itemCoupon = 'yes' OR person.itemReturned = 'yes')

LEFT JOIN owners AS inTime 
ON person.id= inTime.id 
AND purchases.date 
BETWEEN purchases.date 
DATE( '2000-01-01' )
AND 
DATE( '2000-01-05' ) 
GROUP BY purchases.brand
```